# ScrollView Frame.Navigate Null

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to navigate to a page from a ScrollViewer control:

```
  <Button x:Name="btnViewMenu" Content="View Menu" Click="btnViewMenu_Click" Margin="0,20,0,0" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Grid.Row="3" />

 private void btnViewMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RestaurantLocation loc = btn.CommandParameter as RestaurantLocation;
        App.CurrentRestaurantLocation = loc;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SearchFormPage));
    }
```

On the search form page, I get this error:

_pageKey cannot be null:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page will no longer be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property provides the group to be displayed.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
        var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        this.SaveState(pageState);
        frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;
    }
```

Am I navigating improperly? This only happens inside of a scrollviewer.

Comment: might this apply?: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a2611a92-4d2e-4186-9118-cde94346c756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I had to call the base method:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        List<string> theResults = e.Parameter as List<string>;
        city = theResults[0];
        state = theResults[1];
        category = theResults[2];
        BindData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you a calling base.OnNavigatedTo(e) and base.OnNavigatedFrom(e)

in overrided methods after execution of your logic